# Too many messages - The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action

Tags: flutter, firebase-admob

After the admob was added to the project and used I constantly get such messages in console when nothing happens on screen adn the app gets too slow.

> I/Ads     ( 3001): This request is sent from a test device.
>
> W/Ads     ( 3001): #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
>
> I/chatty  ( 3001): uid=10080(com.github.testapp) identical 1 line
>
> W/Ads     ( 3001): #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
>
> E/eglCodecCommon( 3001): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
>
> I/chatty  ( 3001): uid=10080(com.github.testapp) RenderThread
> identical 18 lines
>
> E/eglCodecCommon( 3001): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
>
> W/Ads     ( 3001): #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
>
> I/chatty  ( 3001): uid=10080(com.github.testapp) identical 1 line
>
> W/Ads     ( 3001): #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
>
> I/Choreographer( 3001): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be
> doing too much work on its main thread.
>
> E/eglCodecCommon( 3001): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
>
> I/chatty  ( 3001): uid=10080(com.github.testapp) RenderThread
> identical 88 lines
>
> E/eglCodecCommon( 3001): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5
>
> D/EGL_emulation( 3001): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe63abce0: ver 3 0 (tinfo
> 0xbf992bc0)
>
> E/eglCodecCommon( 3001): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5

I used it in a Stateless widget this way:

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    BannerAd _currentBannerAd = BannerAd(
      adUnitId: AdManager.bannerAdUnitId,
      size: AdSize.banner,
    );
    
    void _loadBannerAd() {
      _currentBannerAd
        ..load()
        ..show(anchorType: AnchorType.bottom);
    }
    
    _loadBannerAd();

    return FutureBuilder<List<String>>(...
```

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue. The ad is showing on even on those screens which don't have Admob code.

Comment: @PallavChaudhari you have to dispose your BannerAd to switch it off. Until then, the add will be on every screen.

Comment: Yes I kind of figured that out after messing with the codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/banner/get-started#display_ad), `dispose()` should be called when access to the ad is no longer needed. The cause for the app slow down is likely because of the ad being initialized multiple times without being disposed.